# The requested address is not valid in this context

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF rest service define like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        DOMConfigurator.Configure();
        string serviceUriStr = "http://127.0.0.1:9001/AFMServer";
        Uri serviceUri = new Uri(serviceUriStr);
        _webHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(AftermathFacade), serviceUri);
        WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.None);
        binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2000000000;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2000000000;
        //binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        //binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        //binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        ////binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        _webHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IAftermathFacade), binding, serviceUriStr);

        ServiceThrottlingBehavior stb = new ServiceThrottlingBehavior();
        stb.MaxConcurrentCalls = 1000;
        stb.MaxConcurrentInstances = 1000;
        stb.MaxConcurrentSessions = 1000;

        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        _webHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
        _webHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(stb);


        _webHost.Open();
        _log.Info("Listening on Uri: " + serviceUri.AbsoluteUri);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _log.Error(ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Accessing this service from a client randomly throws a

> "The requested address is not valid in this context"

exception. Sometimes it does, sometimes it does not and the remote call works.

What I noticed is that it seems to happen when to calls to the service are made too quickly.

for instance:

```
CallServiceMethod1();
CallSericeMethod2();
```

throws an exception.

However:

```
CallServiceMethod1();
sleep(1000);
CallSericeMethod2();
```

Works!

Any idea where the problem might be coming from?

Note that the service is hosted on a AWS micro instance (very poor performance). When I test locally on my box, the exception is not happening as often.